# Lagrangian Multipliers Constrained Optimization

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, stationary-point

As far as I understand, Lagrangian multiplier $\lambda$ can take negative and positive values. For the positive values, we find maximum point. For the negative values, we find minimum point.

I think that we cannot find minimum point by using Lagrangian multipliers for this functions:

$f(x, y) = x^2y^2$

$g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 = 1$

I aim to find minimum and maximum point of $f$ under the condition $g$.

When I apply Lagrangian method, I could find only this solution:

$x = \sqrt\lambda$

$y = \sqrt\lambda$

When I substituted these equalities in $g(x, y)$, I found $\lambda = 1/2$, and $f(x, y) = 1/4$.

What do you think about this ?

There is only positive Lagrangian value, and it makes function $f(x, y)$ produce $1/4$. Is this maximum value or minimum value ? I think it is maximum point.

Comment: Who told you that the sign of the Lagrange multiplier determines if you have a local maximum or a local minimum? If you have $x^2/4+y^2$ constrained to the unit circle, for example, the Lagrange multipliers all have the same sign, but one pair of solutions gives you local maxima and the other local minima. In any case, there are five solutions to the system of equations that the Lagrange multiplier method generates for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Step by step

$$
L = x^2y^2-\lambda(x^2+y^2-1)
$$

so the stationary points (maxima, minima, saddle) are included in the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 =\cases{2xy^2-2\lambda x\\
2y x^2-2\lambda y\\
x^2+y^2-1}
$$

from the first two equations we have $x=0,y=0,y^2=\lambda, x^2 = \lambda$ so substituting into the third we have $2\lambda = 1$ or $\lambda^* = \frac 12$ hence $x^* = \pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},\ \ y^* = \pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ or for any $\lambda$ also $x^* = 0,y^* =\pm 1,\ \ y^*=0,x^*= \pm 1$. Now among those stationary points we should choose according to our needs. Substituting the restriction on the objective function we have

$$
z = x^2(1-x^2),\ \ -1\le x \le 1
$$

so at $x^*=\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ we have two maxima and at $x^* = 0, x^*=\pm 1$ we have minima as can be depicted from the following plot

[image]

Resuming the stationary points

$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
x^* & y^* & \lambda^* & x^2y^2 & \text{type}\\
0  & \pm 1 & \text{any} & 0 & \text{min}\\
\pm 1  & 0 & \text{any} & 0 & \text{min}\\
\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2} & \frac 12 & \frac 14 & \text{max}
\end{array}
$$

NOTE

The restriction of $z = x^2y^2$ on the cylinder $x^2+y^2-1=0$ can be depicted in blue in the following plot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have found the maximum.

When solving the Euler-Lagrange equations, you ignored that the derivatives of the Lagrangian with respect to $x$ and $y$ can also be zero when $(x,y)=(0,\sqrt\lambda)$ or $(x,y)=(\sqrt\lambda,0)$. Then you get $\lambda=1$, and $$f(x,y)=0$$which is the minimum.

[image]

Comment: I think that x and y cannot be equal to zero at the same time, since it does not satisfy the circle constraint $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Hence, The only $(x,y)$ pair which validates Lagrangian method is $(\sqrt\lambda, \sqrt\lambda)$.

Comment: @Goktug to clarify **no**, the only $(x,y)$ pair which validates the Lagrange method is **not** $(\sqrt\lambda,\sqrt\lambda)$. There are many others. $$(-\sqrt\lambda,\sqrt\lambda)\\(-\sqrt\lambda,-\sqrt\lambda)\\(\sqrt\lambda,-\sqrt\lambda)\\(\pm\sqrt\lambda,0)\\(0,\pm\sqrt\lambda)$$The bottom ones are minima, the upper ones are maxima.

Comment: The bottom ones do not satisfy the following formula if we do not assume that $\lambda$ is equal to zero. $\nabla f = \left<2xy^2, 2x^2y\right> = \lambda \left<2x, 2y\right> = \lambda \nabla g$

Comment: @Goktug Ah yes, the derivative is non zero in one of the directions. However, it is still minimised there with respect to the constraint. See my edit. The derivative in the perpendicular direction need not be zero at points on the constraint curve which are tangential to the $x$ or $y$ directions, since these aren't directions along which one can minimise.